# NHibernate PreSelect?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, preloading

I am trying to implement privileges using NHibernate, and what I want to do, is each time there is a Select query, check what the return type is, and if it is a security enabled type (such as invoices) i want to add restrictions to the ICriteria object, to restrict retrieving only certain records (According if the user has read all, or read own privileges).

I managed to implement these kind of privileges for Insert and Update using

```
NHibernater.Event.IPreUpdateEventListener
NHibernater.Event.IPreInsertEventListener
```

but unfortunately the `IPreLoadEventListener` is called after the database is queried, and therefore it is waste as the filtering will be done locally on the computer rather then by the database.

Does anyone know if NHibernate provides some sort of event that is called before a query is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to use it, check out [Rhino.Security](https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-security) It does exactly what you're trying to do. Even if you're unable to use it, you can then see his implementation of this problem.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to use it, but having a real hard time :( right now i'm thinking of implementing Frederik's solution with filters.

Comment: @LnDCobra, yeah there isn't a lot of documentation about it.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you achieve this by using Filters ?

More information can be found [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/04/nhibernate-filters.aspx)

I've used this in combination with Interceptors in a project of mine:

I have some entities where each user can create instances from, but only the user who has created them, should be able to see / modify those instances.  Other users cannot see instances created by user X.

In order to that, I've created an interface `IUserContextAware`.  Entities that are 'user context aware' implement this interface.

When building my session-factory, I created the necessary filters:

```
 var currentUserFilterParametersType = new Dictionary<string, NHibernate.Type.IType> (1);
 currentUserFilterParametersType.Add (CurrentUserContextFilterParameter, NHibernateUtil.Guid);
 cfg.AddFilterDefinition (new FilterDefinition (CurrentUserContextFilter,
                                                           "(:{0} = UserId or UserId is null)".FormatString (CurrentUserContextFilterParameter),
                                                           currentUserFilterParametersType,
                                                           false));
```

When this was done, I needed to define the additional filter criteria:

```
 foreach( var mapping in cfg.ClassMappings )
 {
    if( typeof (IUserContextAware).IsAssignableFrom (mapping.MappedClass) )
    {
       // The filter should define the names of the columns that are used in the DB, rather then propertynames.
      // Therefore, we need to have a look at the mapping information.

      Property userProperty = mapping.GetProperty ("UserId");

      foreach( Column c in userProperty.ColumnIterator )
      {
          string filterExpression = ":{0} = {1}";

          // When the BelongsToUser field is not mandatory, NULL should be taken into consideration as well.
          // (For instance: a PrestationGroup instance that is not User-bound (that can be used by any user), will have
          //  a NULL value in its BelongsToUser field).
          if( c.IsNullable )
          {
              filterExpression = filterExpression + " or {1} is null";
          }

          mapping.AddFilter (CurrentUserContextFilter, "(" + filterExpression.FormatString (CurrentUserContextFilterParameter, c.Name) + ")");
          break;
     }
 }
```

Now, whenever I instantiate an `ISession`, I specify that a certain interceptor should be used:

This interceptor makes sure that the parameter in the filter is populated:

```
    internal class ContextAwareInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
    {
        public override void SetSession( ISession session )
        {
            if( AppInstance.Current == null )
            {
                return;
            }

            // When a User is logged on, the CurrentUserContextFilter should be enabled.
            if( AppInstance.Current.CurrentUser != null )
            {
                session.EnableFilter (AppInstance.CurrentUserContextFilter)
                                            .SetParameter (AppInstance.CurrentUserContextFilterParameter,
                                                           AppInstance.Current.CurrentUser.Id);

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This sounds perfect to me :) Thanks! This article helped alot to udnerstand filters better :P http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#filters

Comment: Actually, i just realised that this won't work, as i have a permissions table and therefore the filter would change all the time for all different entities ( and even the same entity over time)